# Python virtualenv not working on MacOS Seirra

Tags: macos, python

Creating a virtual environment fails on MacOSX Seirra

When running `virtualenv test`

```
New python executable in /Users/sri/test/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in /Users/sri/test/bin/python
Please make sure you remove any previous custom paths from your /Users/sri/.pydistutils.cfg file.
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
  Complete output from command /Users/sri/test/bin/python2.7 - setuptools pip wheel:
  Collecting setuptools
  Using cached setuptools-35.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pip
Collecting wheel
Collecting six>=1.6.0 (from setuptools)
  Using cached six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting packaging>=16.8 (from setuptools)
  Using cached packaging-16.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting appdirs>=1.4.0 (from setuptools)
  Using cached appdirs-1.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyparsing (from packaging>=16.8->setuptools)
  Using cached pyparsing-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: six, pyparsing, packaging, appdirs, setuptools, pip, wheel
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/wheel.py", line 323, in clobber
    shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py'
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 713, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 945, in create_environment
    download=download,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 901, in install_wheel
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 797, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /Users/sri/test/bin/python2.7 - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 2
```

When I run the same with sudo `sudo virtualenv venv`
New python executable in /Users/shan/test/bin/python2.7

```
Also creating executable in /Users/shan/test/bin/python
Please make sure you remove any previous custom paths from your /Users/shan/.pydistutils.cfg file.
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
  Complete output from command /Users/shan/test/bin/python2.7 - setuptools pip wheel:
  The directory '/Users/shan/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/shan/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting setuptools
Collecting pip
Collecting wheel
Installing collected packages: setuptools, pip, wheel
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/wheel.py", line 478, in move_wheel_files
    generated.extend(maker.make(spec))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/distlib/scripts.py", line 372, in make
    self._make_script(entry, filenames, options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/distlib/scripts.py", line 276, in _make_script
    self._write_script(scriptnames, shebang, script, filenames, ext)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/distlib/scripts.py", line 250, in _write_script
    self._fileop.write_binary_file(outname, script_bytes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/distlib/util.py", line 407, in write_binary_file
    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
IOError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/bin/easy_install'
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 713, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 945, in create_environment
    download=download,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 901, in install_wheel
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 797, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /Users/shan/test/bin/python2.7 - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Sierra and virtual environments appear to work fine. What python distribution are you using? How did you initiate your virtual environment? I used Anaconda to install python and then followed their directions for setting up and activating virtual environments.